# Can I use KIS (Home Edition) on Win Server 2012 R2

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, kaspersky

I have data server (win server 2012 r2) and I have KasperSky Internet Security (Home Edition), can I install KIS on the server to protect it from malicious SW.